# mysql 5.5 to 8 - how to migrate password

Tags: php, mysql

I have old server with MySQL 5.5 and new server MySQL 8.
I dont know the users password and I need to move about 30 users. 
**What is the right way to copy the 'mysql' database to the new server?**
I tried to copy the mysql as any other regular database, I know that it not recommended,  and got :

> [Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin sha256_password reported: ''sha256_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use caching_sha2_password instead'
> <

How can I convert sha256 to sha2?
I tried also:

> show grants user 'user_name'@'localhost';

Then take the line and run it on the new server(mysql 8):

> create user 'user_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD
> '*1E0C2C7ED8F8315F6816F...';

When I run :
select * from user where user='user_name'

I get different hashed password in the 'authentication_string'  column I have:
*E5FDC4D51AC7AB43AC9...

Any idea?

Comment: _Small Point_ Different HASHED passwords, you are hashing not encrypting

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of differences between MySQL 5.5 and 8.0. That said, you should be able to do it in about three steps:

**1 — Export the Grants**

Run this from the shell of your database server:

```
mysql -u root -p'PASSWORD' --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql -u root -p'PASSWORD' --skip-column-names -A | sed 's/$/;/g' > user_grants.sql
```

This will put all of the grants into the `user_grants.sql` file in a format that is easily importable for the new server.

**2 — Build the Create User Statements**

Run this from the shell of your database server:

```
mysql -u root -p'password' --skip-column-names -A mysql -e "SELECT CONCAT('CREATE USER \'', user, '\'@\'', host, '\' IDENTIFIED WITH \'mysql_native_password\' AS \'', password,'\';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user NOT IN ('mysql.session','mysql.sys','debian-sys-maint','root');" > create_user.sql
```

This will put all of the user accounts into the `create_user.sql` file in a format that is easily importable for the new server.

***Important Note:** This query will work with MySQL 5.6 and lower. From 5.7 the `password` field no longer exists in the `users` table.*

**3 — Restore the Data**

Copy the files to the new server and import the data:

```
mysql -u root -p mysql < create_user.sql
mysql -u root -p mysql < user_grants.sql
```

Once this is done, connect to MySQL and flush the privileges:

```
mysql -u root -p
{enter password}
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
quit;
```

Done.

Comment: When I did section 2 I got the error: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*FD67756553FE...'' at line 1

Comment: @user1980099, edit the `user_grants.sql` and remove the "IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password'" occurrences. MySQL 8 does not accept that part of the command.

Answer (score 2):

Needed to change part two, as no password column exist. Changed to:

> authentication_string

```
mysql -u root -p'password' --skip-column-names -A mysql -e "SELECT CONCAT('CREATE USER \'', user, '\'@\'', host, '\' IDENTIFIED WITH \'mysql_native_password\' AS \'', authentication_string,'\';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user NOT IN ('mysql.session','mysql.sys','debian-sys-maint','root');" > create_user.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone else needs, the following statement works from mysql 5.4 to 8.0.27,

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=150000000;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(concat('DROP USER IF EXISTS ''',user,'''@''',host,''';'),
                        '\n',
                        concat('CREATE USER ''',user,'''@''',host,''' ', ' IDENTIFIED WITH ''mysql_native_password'' AS ''',Password,"'",' REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS ', max_user_connections,' PASSWORD EXPIRE DEFAULT ACCOUNT UNLOCK;'),
                        '\n',
                       concat( 'GRANT',
                                IF(  Select_priv = 'y',' SELECT,',''),
                                IF(  Insert_priv = 'y',' INSERT,',''),
                                 IF(  Update_priv = 'y',' UPDATE,',''),
                                 IF(  Delete_priv = 'y',' DELETE,',''),
                                 IF(  Create_priv = 'y',' CREATE,',''),
                                 IF(  Drop_priv = 'y',' DROP,',''),
                                 IF(  Reload_priv = 'y',' RELOAD,',''),
                                 IF(  Shutdown_priv = 'y',' SHUTDOWN,',''),
                                 IF(  Process_priv = 'y',' PROCESS,',''),
                                 IF(  File_priv = 'y',' FILE,',''),
                                 IF(  References_priv = 'y',' REFERENCES,',''),
                                 IF(  Index_priv = 'y',' INDEX,',''),
                                 IF(  Alter_priv = 'y',' ALTER,',''),
                                 IF(  Show_db_priv = 'y',' SHOW DATABASES,',''),
                                 IF(  Super_priv = 'y',' SUPER,',''),
                                 IF(  Create_tmp_table_priv = 'y',' CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,',''),
                                 IF(  Lock_tables_priv = 'y',' LOCK TABLES,',''),
                                 IF(  Execute_priv = 'y',' EXECUTE,',''),
                                 IF(  Repl_slave_priv = 'y',' REPLICATION SLAVE,',''),
                                 IF(  Repl_client_priv = 'y',' REPLICATION CLIENT,',''),
                                 IF(  Create_view_priv = 'y',' CREATE VIEW,',''),
                                 IF(  Show_view_priv = 'y',' SHOW VIEW,',''),
                                 IF(  Create_routine_priv = 'y',' CREATE ROUTINE,',''),
                                 IF(  Alter_routine_priv = 'y',' ALTER ROUTINE,',''),
                                 IF(  Create_user_priv = 'y',' CREATE USER,',''),
                                 IF(  Event_priv = 'y',' EVENT,',''),
                                 IF(  Trigger_priv = 'y',' TRIGGER,',''),
                                 IF(  Create_tablespace_priv = 'y',' CREATE TABLESPACE','')
                                , " ON *.* TO '",user,"'@'",host,"' WITH GRANT OPTION;"),
                                '\n',
                                "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;")
                                separator '\n'
                                )as selec FROM MYSQL.user;
```

Cheers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).