# Script user creation with grant statements for all MySQL.user values

Tags: mysql

I've used a statement in this post authored by avalos to script user creation with grant statements for all MySQl.user values:
[mysql 5.5 to 8 - how to migrate password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65721609/mysql-5-5-to-8-how-to-migrate-password)

There are numerous users but only one is being returned partially:

DROP USER IF EXISTS 'xxxxx'@'%';
CREATE USER 'xxxxx'@'%'  IDENTIFIED WITH 'mysql_native_password' AS '*9455E5B0ADDFBF35D44ACEF2A4FB38265F5A110B' REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 PASSWORD EXPIRE DEFAULT ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
GRANT ON *.* TO 'xxxx...

I am using exactly the statement in the referenced post, to include the group_concat_max_len enlargement at top:   SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=150000000;

Can anyone tell me what is terminating my result string?